# How to join a table with one column of a view in that table's entity class

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

**Scenario:**

- I have a products table with these fields: id, code, description, photo.
- I have a product_stock view from other schema with fields: prod_code, stok_tot

**Misson:** What I need to do in `Spring Boot` is to join the products with their total stock.

**Rules:**

- I can't use `@Query` on this task, I need to join them at the *Product* `Entity Class`, so that `stock` became some kind of *Transient* field of product.
- I can't change the fact that product's ID is a `Long` and ProductStock's ID is a `String`, but I could use product's code field instead right? (how?)

**So far...** I tryed to use @OneToOne and @JoinColumn to do the job, but my `REST` gives me the stock field as `NULL`.

"Estoque.java"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VW_ESTOQUE", schema = "ASICAT")
public class Estoque {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CD_BEM_SERVICO", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String codigo;

    @Column(name = "ESTOQUE")
    private Long estoque;

    // getters and setters hidden by me
}
```

"Produto.java"

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Produto.detail", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("categorias"))
public class Produto implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String codigo;

    private String descricao;

    // here is where I get the null values
    @Transient
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "VW_ESTOQUE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGO", referencedColumnName = "CODIGO"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CD_BEM_SERVICO", referencedColumnName = "CODIGO"))
    private Estoque estoque;

    private String hash;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "produtos", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @BatchSize(size = 10)
    private List<Categoria> categorias = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters hidden by me

}
```

*In my product repository I call FindAll()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have annotated `Produto.estoque` as `@Transient`, which means that it is not part of the persistent state of the entity.  Such a field will be neither written *nor read* when instances of that entity are managed.  That's not going to serve your purpose.

There are two things I can imagine you might have been trying to achieve:

1. That every time an `Estoque` is accessed via a `Produto`, it should be loaded from the DB to ensure its freshness.  JPA does not provide for that, though you might want to annotate `Estoque` with `@Cacheable(value = false)`, and specify the lazy fetch strategy on the `Produto` side of the relationship.
2. You want to avoid the persistence provider attempting to persist any changes to an `Estoque`, since it is backed by a view, not an updatable table.  *This* we can address.

My first suggestion would be to map `ASICAT.VW_ESTOQUE` as a secondary table instead of an entirely separate entity.  That might look something like this:

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name = "VW_ESTOQUE", schema = "ASICAT"
        pkJoinColumns = {
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "CD_BEM_SERVICO",
                    referencedColumnName = "CODIGO") })
public class Produto implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String codigo;

    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "ESTOQUE", table = "VW_ESTOQUE", nullable = true,
            insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long estoque;

    // ...
}
```

You might furthermore avoid providing a setter for the `estoque` property.

But the `SecondaryTable` approach might not work well if you cannot rely on the `ESTOQUE` view always to provide a row for every row of `PRODUTO`, as there will very likely be an inner join involved in retrievals.  Moreover, you don't get lazy fetches this way.  The main alternative is more or less what you present in your question: to set up a separate `Estoque` entity.

If you *do* set up a separate `Estoque`, however, then I would approach it a bit differently.  Specifically,

- I would make the relationship bidirectional, so that I could
- make the `Estoque` entity the relationship owner.

Something like this, then:

```
@Entity
public class Produto implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String codigo;

    private String descricao;

    // must not be @Transient:
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "produto", cascade = {
            CascadeType.REFRESH
        })
    private Estoque estoque;

    // ...    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "VW_ESTOQUE", schema = "ASICAT")
@Cacheable(value = false)
public class Estoque {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CD_BEM_SERVICO", nullable = false,
            insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String codigo;

    @Column(name = "ESTOQUE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long estoque;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_BEM_SERVICO", referencedColumnName = "CODIGO",
        nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    Produto produto;

    // getters and setters hidden by me
}
```

In this case, I would avoid providing setter methods for any of the properties of `Estoque`, and avoid providing any constructor that allows initial property values to be set.  Thus, to a first approximation, the only 
way an instance's properties will take non-null values is if they are set by the persistence provider.

Additionally, since you mention Oracle, if you are using TopLink as your persistence provider then you might consider applying its `@ReadOnly` extension attribute to the `Estoque` entity, in place of or even in addition to some of these protections against trying to insert into or update the view.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will test both approaches on Monday. I will use the that works. I don't need Estoque to be an entity anyway, nether to be lazy.

Comment: In your first example: SecondaryTable JoinColumn cannot reference a non primary key